# How to skip an empty sheet in an Excel source

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an Excel workbook, which I'm importing into a SQL Server database using SSIS. Each sheet contains different information. For most sheets the first row has column names. For the most part each worksheet has its own package that is run from a master package in order.

For one of the workbooks that I need to import one of the sheets has no data. It has the column names in the first row, but nothing past that. Whenever I try to import this workbook it fails on that worksheet (I'll edit with the exact error message as soon as I get it next run). I can get around this by disabling that package for the run if I'm doing it manually, but now it needs to be automated. How can I get SSIS to skip the worksheet if no rows exist past the header row?

Comment: Check out this article below. You can query the sheet based on a range; https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/bi-sql-server/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/